# Mean: Query related collections gives 'findOne' of undefined

Tags: mongodb, express, mean-stack

Im new to MEAN and I have **two collection users & dashboard.** I have **related** dashboard to user

Mongo shell

> db.users.find() ->  { "_id" : ObjectId("573765e5889380a83581f421"), "firstName" : "zx", "lastName" : "zx", "username" : "zx" }
>
> db.dashboard.find() -> { "_id" : ObjectId("573766af2affdfa8aaef44d4"), "sentenceId" : 40, "synced" : 1, "iscorrect" : "no", "user_id" : ObjectId("573765e5889380a83581f421") }

As we can observe that users is related with dashboard

> db.dashboard.findOne({"user_id" :
>   ObjectId("573765e5889380a83581f421")})

result obtained is

> { "_id" : ObjectId("573766af2affdfa8aaef44d4"), "sentenceId" : 40,
>   "synced" : 1, "iscorrect" : "no", "user_id" :
>   ObjectId("573765e5889380a83581f421") }

Problem start from here

I trying to do in express js as follows

```
function getById(_id) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    db.dashboard.findOne({user_id : _id}, function (err, user) {
        console.log(user)

        if (err) deferred.reject(err);

        if (user) {
            // return user (without hashed password)
            deferred.resolve(_.omit(user, 'hash'));
        } else {
            // user not found
            deferred.resolve();
        }
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Error Message `TypeError: Cannot read property 'findOne' of undefined`

Im using **mongoskin** and Im not sure **how to implement** `db.dashboard.findOne` in express

Any **better approach** can also be suggested, Any help is appreciated

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are referencing the `dashboard` collection seems to be wrong.

You could either bind the db instance to the collection or use the `collection` method.

With `db.bind`:

```
function getById(_id) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    db.bind('dashboard');
    db.dashboard.findOne({user_id : _id}, function (err, user) {
        console.log(user)

        if (err) deferred.reject(err);

        if (user) {
            // return user (without hashed password)
            deferred.resolve(_.omit(user, 'hash'));
        } else {
            // user not found
            deferred.resolve();
        }
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

With `db.collection`:

```
function getById(_id) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    var dashboard = db.collection('dashboard');
    dashboard.findOne({user_id : _id}, function (err, user) {
        console.log(user)

        if (err) deferred.reject(err);

        if (user) {
            // return user (without hashed password)
            deferred.resolve(_.omit(user, 'hash'));
        } else {
            // user not found
            deferred.resolve();
        }
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply....I get result as null when I console the value..I wanted to query something like this db.dashboard.findOne({"user_id" : ObjectId("573765e5889380a83581f421")})..................... how should I add ObjectId in express?